# Firebase.instance.signOut() not setting the currentUser() to null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Why is my signOut() method not setting the currentUser() to null??

When I click on logout on my homepage it checks the isAuthenticated() method which is returning a user instead of null. Also, just have a look at the two comments I've included inside the logout() method. 
Thank You!!

Here's my code -

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  bool isAuthenticated() {
    print('$currentUser inside the isAuthenticated');
    if (currentUser == null) {
      print('false');
      return false;
    }
    print('true');
    return true;
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> get currentUser async {
    return await _auth.currentUser();
  }


  Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final response = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      print(response);

      if (response == null) {
        print('response is null');
      } else {
        notifyListeners();
        return response.user;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('some error');
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount _userDetails = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (_userDetails == null) {
        print('No user found');
      } else {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
            await _userDetails.authentication;

        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        );

        final FirebaseUser user =
            (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;

        return user;
      }
      notifyListeners();
      print('google sign in ran successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> logout() async {
    try {
      print('logout ran');
      print(currentUser);       //THIS RETURNS AN INSTANCE OF USER
      _auth.signOut().then( (response) {
        print('signout successful');
      });

      await _googleSignIn.signOut();
      print(currentUser);     //THIS *ALSO* RETURNS AN INSTANCE OF USER
      notifyListeners();
      return currentUser;
    } catch (error) {
      print('an error');
    }
  }
}
```

I know there would a silly mistake that I'm unable to catch but it's tiring now!! I've tried other methods that I could find on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

May be the future is not complete when you try getting current user, have you tried await instead of then in logout?

```
Future<FirebaseUser> logout() async {
    try {
      print('logout ran');
      print(currentUser);       //THIS RETURNS AN INSTANCE OF USER
      await _auth.signOut();

      await _googleSignIn.signOut();
      //The problem is with this, you need to await this
      //print(currentUser);     //THIS *ALSO* RETURNS AN INSTANCE OF USER
      var user = await currentUser;
      print(user); //prints null
      notifyListeners();
      return currentUser;
    } catch (error) {
      print('an error');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tried and tested. Same issue.

Comment: You have a return statement with  currentUser,  does it also return the currentUser instead of null?

Comment: Yes, if you are talking about the currentUser getter then I tried printing the response before the return in the getter and it returns an instance of user

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and worked it around by assigning null to currentUser. It works fine now!

```
        case R.id.main_logout_option:
            updateUserStatus(getString(R.string.strOffline));
            mAuth.signOut();
            currentUser = null;
            goToLoginActivity();
            break;
```